# Release Azure Functions and file transformations

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a lot of Azure Functions projects to deploy on Azure. I set build and pipeline for them. For example, this is one **Release** for an Azure Function.

[image: Azure DevOps Release]

Under **Variables** I defined all variables for the environments (one for dev, one for stage and one for production).

[image: Variables]

There is only one step for deploying the Azure Functions on Azure. I want to add/replace in the `local.settings.json` the right settings for an environment. I'm not be able to find how to configure that.

[image: Deploy Azure Function App]

In other project, if I use `Azure App Service Deploy`, there is a section `File Transforms & Variable Substitution Options`.

[image: File transformations]

How can I do the same in the release of an Azure Functions? What is the correct strategy or best practice?

### Update and Solution

I thought it was much straightforward. I think this is the solution. In the **App settings** under **Application and Configuration Settings**, I have to specified each variable and its value using the `...` in that line.

[image]

[image]

I can type or copy in this field. The syntax is

```
-variableName "$(variablename)"
```

I'm using quotes because if in the value there is any space (for example in the connection string you have `Initial Catalog`) DevOps raises an error. For array, I'm still using `:`.

Comment: Hi Enrico You donot need to  specify each variable and its value in App settings, You can make use of File Transform task. Please check out below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to use [File Transform task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops) to substitute the variables in local.settings.json file with pipeline variables. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#json-variable-substitution) for more information.

With File Transform task, you donot have to specify each variable and its value in App settings of deploy Azure Functions task.

You can add a File Transform task before the deploy Azure Functions task. Then define the variables(eg. `KeyVaultSettings.ClientId`) in your pipeline variables.

[image]

Then set the **Package or folder**, **file format** and **Target files** in File Transform task. See below:

[image]

Comment: In `Package or folder` I left the defaut one `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip` beause `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` ends up in an error

Comment: I have an issue with this file transform. If I open Kudu, I find in the `local.settings.json` my local settings but I expected to see the settings in the variables section. The only difference is in `Package or folder` I use `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip` because `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` generated an error (Error: NO JSON file matched with specific pattern: **/local.settings.json.) @Levi

Comment: Is it your local setttings failed to be replaced with the settings in the pipeline varilables? You can check out this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#json-variable-substitution) to make sure the variables in pipelines has the right names.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've done in my Azure Functions pipeline (it's yaml, but you'll get the idea).

1. Create one stage per environment in your pipeline
2. Create your pipelines variables and asign a different value based on scope (stage)
3. Create a configuration entry (see picture) in your pipeline and asign the variable value.
4. Consume the configuration entry in your Azure Function (in my case I use Environmental Variables for that)

[Use pipeline environment in your azure function configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6ve7.png)